# Como obtengo consecutivos similares de mi string?

Tags: javascript, string

Buscando unos ejercicios para refrescar un poco JS me piden esto:

```
Debes crear una función llamada “consecutivosSimilares” que reciba un string y retorne
cuantos consecutivos similares hay en un string.
Ejemplo:
- consecutivosSimilares(“AAAA”) debe retornar 3
- consecutivosSimilares(“BBBBB”) debe retornar 4
- consecutivosSimilares(“ABABABAB”) debe retornar 0
- consecutivosSimilares(“BABABA”) debe retornar 0
- consecutivosSimilares(“AAABBB”) debe retornar 4
*/
```

Pero no logro dar con la logica para que se recorra el string y vaya comparando con el caracter anterior :S si es que esa sea la forma...

```
const consecutivosSimilares=(palabra=String)=>{
    contador=0
    p=0 //posicion 1
    p1=1 //posicion 2
    while((palabra[p]==palabra[p1])){
        contador++
        p++
        p1++
    }
    
console.log(contador)
}


consecutivosSimilares("BABABA")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente guarda el valor de la letra actual. Si la letra actual es igual a la letra guardada, incrementa el contador. Si es diferente, actualiza la letra actual.

```js
const consecutivosSimilares = (palabra) => {
    if (palabra.length <= 1) return 0;

    let letraActual = palabra[0];
    let consecutivos = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i < palabra.length; i++) {
        if (palabra[i] === letraActual) {
            consecutivos++;
        } else {
            letraActual = palabra[i];
        }
    }

    return consecutivos;
}

console.log(`consecutivosSimilares("AAAA") retorna ${consecutivosSimilares("AAAA")}`)
console.log(`consecutivosSimilares("BBBBB") retorna ${consecutivosSimilares("BBBBB")}`)
console.log(`consecutivosSimilares("ABABABAB") retorna ${consecutivosSimilares("ABABABAB")}`)
console.log(`consecutivosSimilares("BABABA") retorna ${consecutivosSimilares("BABABA")}`)
console.log(`consecutivosSimilares("AAABBB") retorna ${consecutivosSimilares("AAABBB")}`)
```